# Can I restore my Yoroi account with only 12 words?

Tags: wallet, yoroi

Yoroi wants 15 words from me, but I only wrote down 12. I know it was a Shelley wallet, and can see all details about my Cardano.

Can I restore my account without seed phrase?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yoroi uses 15 words for its seed phrase. You did probably used Daedalus to generate it. I recommend you to try to use [Daedalus](https://daedaluswallet.io/) to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

This table represents which length of seed phrases was used in wallets during the Byron-era (legacy) and which one in the today's Shelley-era wallets. By the way the ***cardano-wallet*** is a command-line tool allowing you to use a first-factor seed phrase 15-24 word, and an optional second-factor seed phrase 9-12 word.

| Wallet | Byron-era | Shelley-era |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Daedalus | 12-word | 24-word |
| Yoroi | 15-word | 15-word |
| cardano-wallet | 15-word, 18-word, 21-word, 24-word | 15-word, 18-word, 21-word, 24-word |